# True of false - Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Check if the following affirmatives are true or false:

a) $f$ is a surjective linear transformation that maps $V$ to $W$, if and only if $\dim \ker \mbox{f} = \dim \mbox{V} - \dim \mbox{W}$.

b) If $f$ is and endomorphism of $V$, so $V = \ker \mbox{f} \oplus \mbox{im}\mbox{f}$.

c) If $f$ is a linear transformation that maps $R^5$ to $R^3$, so $\dim \ker \mbox{f} \geq 3$.

My answers:

a) True

b) True

C) False

For a:
$$
\dim \mbox{V} =  \dim \mbox{im} \mbox{f} + \dim \ker \mbox{f}
$$
if $\dim \mbox{im} \mbox{f} = \dim \mbox{W}$ f will be surjective, hence:
$$
\dim \ker \mbox{f} = \dim \mbox{V} - \dim \mbox{W}
$$ 
Makes my previous statement true.

For b:

If we choose any vector in $V$, it'll be in the range, or in the image of that endomorphism, since any endomorphism is surjective. By that, we can assume that the direct sum of the kernel and image will contain any vector in $V$.

For c:

I used the rank-nullity theorem:
$$
\dim R^5 = \dim \ker \mbox{f} + \dim \mbox{im} \mbox{f}\\
\dim \mbox{im} \mbox{f} = \dim R^3 = 3\\
\dim \ker \mbox{f} = 5 - 3 = 2
$$

Am I correct?! Do I need to be more rigorous in b, or that's good enough?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An endomorphism need not be surjective. Consider for instance the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ as a counterexample to (b).

Similarly, $f$ need not be surjective in (c). There *exists* one such $f$, however, and for such a map the rank-nullity theorem says that $\dim \ker f = 2$, as you've argued.

Comment: So for a and c i'm correct?!

Comment: @BrunoReis a) is true. For c), you should exhibit a particular $f$ which invalidates the claim.